# with C++ shortest path algorithm with two numbers. (c++)

Tags: c++

if I got two integer a, b, I have to get the number of cases 2-D shortest path.
If a = 2, b = 3,

```
h- - - 
| | | |
 - - - 
| | | | 
 - - -g
```

the path is from h to g.

Could you tell me how to get the number of cases with C++?

Comment: you question is unclear. Even if you clarify what you mean please read this: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @bolov I guess ```a``` and ```b``` are the number of rows and columns in his 2d matrix.

Comment: If the number of lines is the shortest path then it is a+b

Comment: @junghokim you are looking for [Manhattan Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Comment: OP asks for number of distinct paths not shortest path so RRRDD, RRDRD and so on. This is a combinatorics problem really - specifically https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5+choose+2 so you need to implement (a+b)!/(a!*b!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of (shortest) paths, it would be

```
(a + b)! / (a! * b!)
```

`!` denote factorial
(permutation count with repetition).

(`10` in your case as `5!/(2!*3!)`).

[`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) would be a good tool to iterate over them.